# QFT Scattering Cross Section Integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering-cross-section

I came across this integral studying QFT regarding what I think it may be the calculation of a 2$\rightarrow$2 particle scattering cross section.

$$I = \int \frac{dp_3}{(2\pi)^32E_3} \frac{d p_4}{(2\pi)^32E_4} \delta^4(p_1+p_2-p_3-p_4) \delta (t-(p_1-p_3)^2)$$

where $p_i$ is the 4-momentum of each particle ($p_1,p_2$ in, $p_3, p_4$ out) and $t$ is the second Mandelstam variable. Does anynone know how to deal with the last Dirac's delta? I have already computed several cross sections but this extra delta puzzles me.

*(The integral is invariant under orthochronous Lorentz transformations so it can be carried out in the LAB, CM or whichever frame of reference)*